# How can I get the public IP using python2.7?

Tags: python, ip

How can I get the public IP using python2.7? Not private IP.

Comment: I'd agree with this post as a duplicate -- same answers anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a public facing IP address in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166545/finding-a-public-facing-ip-address-in-python)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Currently there are several options:

- ip.42.pl
- jsonip.com
- httpbin.org
- ipify.org

Below are exact ways you can utilize each of the above.

### ip.42.pl

```py
from urllib2 import urlopen
my_ip = urlopen('http://ip.42.pl/raw').read()
```

This is the first option I have found. It is very convenient for scripts, you don't need JSON parsing here.

### jsonip.com

```py
from json import load
from urllib2 import urlopen

my_ip = load(urlopen('https://ipv4.jsonip.com'))['ip']
```

Seemingly the sole purpose of this domain is to return IP address in JSON.

### httpbin.org

```py
from json import load
from urllib2 import urlopen

my_ip = load(urlopen('http://httpbin.org/ip'))['origin']
```

httpbin.org is service I often recommend to junior developers to use for testing their scripts / applications.

### ipify.org

```py
from json import load
from urllib2 import urlopen

my_ip = load(urlopen('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json'))['ip']
```

Power of this service results from lack of limits (there is no rate limiting), infrastructure (placed on Heroku, with high availability in mind) and flexibility (works for both IPv4 and IPv6).

**EDIT**: Added [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org) to the list of available options.

**EDIT**: Added [ipify.org](http://www.ipify.org/) thanks to [kert's note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481419/how-can-i-get-the-public-ip-using-python2-7/9481595?noredirect=1#comment48399540_9481595).

Comment: I like icanhazip.com, it's a whole website with just your raw IP; no need to add arrays, formats, etc.

Comment: Just to add for ipify.org: With the url `https://api.ipify.org/?format=raw` you'll get the IP in plaintext, no JSON nonsense.

Comment: https://api.ident.me works too, please fallback to https://tnedi.me if you want to write a complete code example ;)

Answer (score 15):

I like the requests package with http://ip.42.pl/raw

```
import requests
requests.get('http://ip.42.pl/raw').text
```

Answer (score 4):

With **requests** module

```
import requests

public_IP = requests.get("https://www.wikipedia.org").headers["X-Client-IP"]
print public_IP
```

Comment: nice! :) i like this over pinging some random site. i want to say it's more fragile, but i guess it's a bigger name than some of the other sites. As long as they don't change how their headers operate...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import ipgetter
import requests

IP = ipgetter.myip()
url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'+IP
r = requests.get(url)
js = r.json()
print 'IP Adress: '         +   js['ip']
print 'Country Code: '      +   js['country_code']
print 'Country Name: '      +   js['country_name']
print 'Region Code: '       +   js['region_code']
print 'Region Name: '       +   js['region_name']
print 'City Name: '         +   js['city']
print 'Zip code: '          +   js['zip_code']
print 'Time Zone: '         +   js['time_zone']
print 'Latitude: '          +   str(js['latitude'])
print 'Longitude: '         +   str(js['longitude'])
```

Comment: import ipgetter; IP = ipgetter.myip() is enough for the job.

Comment: ipgetter does not (yet) support IPv6, although IPv6 is already celebrating its twentieth birthday. :(

Comment: Dead as of 2022-01-24, try this: http://freegeoip.net/json/1.1.1.1 and it redirects to http://freegeoip.net/shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
import requests
print requests.get("http://ipecho.net/plain?").text
```

Produces:

```
XX.XX.XXX.XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

in python 2.7 it's just a code of 2 lines.

```
>>> import requests
>>print requests.get("http://ipconfig.in/ip").text
```

Comment: Please don't reply to duplicate questions. Mark them as duplicate. It makes SO more organized.

Comment: It's actually three lines if you include `pip install requests`

Answer (score 0):

This is a way not to have to make a call to the internet:

Please let me know if this doesn't work, then I can update the answer (it works for ~10 servers of mine)

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output("/sbin/ifconfig | awk '/inet / { print $2 }' | sed 's/addr://'", shell=True)
[x for x in out.decode().split() if not x == "127.0.0.1" and 
                                    not (x.startswith("172") and x.endswith("0.1"))]
["x.x.x.x.x"]
```