# How to get user public ip in django?

Tags: python, django, ip

I am developing a project that need to store user's last using location, For that i have done like below

the below code from [stackoverflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581997/3531707)

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Here i am getting the user machine ip address(192.xxx.x.xx) not public ip(115.xxx.xxx.xx).How can i get the public address(network provider given).Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481595/3762142

Comment: @rajasimon, How can i get the user's(the end user of my website) ip address there..?

Comment: I think you need to access your site outside of your local network

Comment: @sajadkk, No i need to store user last accessed location.For that i need from where client is accessed my website(So here we need client's external ip address not mine).

Comment: @Mulagala if your site is accessible from internet, you will get user's ip. otherwise it will be your local ip

Comment: @Mulagala just follow that link.. see this link http://jsonip.com/ it will provide you the public address .. am i right ?

Comment: If you're doing your tests with your machine in local you will allways get the IP like '192.xxx.x.xxx'