# How can I get the Public Ip address of my computer without reading text from a url?

Tags: python, ip-address

I would like to get the Public Ip address of my computer.

Many solutions I have seen require requests/urllib2, such as:

```
import requests
requests.get('http://ip.42.pl/raw').text
```

```
import requests

public_IP = requests.get("https://www.wikipedia.org").headers["X-Client-IP"]
print(public_IP)
```

```
from json import load
from urllib2 import urlopen

my_ip = load(urlopen('http://httpbin.org/ip'))['origin']
```

Reference link: [How can I get the public IP using python2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481419/how-can-i-get-the-public-ip-using-python2-7) (Python version doesn't really matter at the moment)

Is there any way to get the public IP without using requests or similar libraries?

Comment: You might be able to use `SNMP` to get it from your router.

Comment: But using APIs like these are probably the best way.

Comment: Without making some type of network request, Python would only know about your local machine, which only has a LAN address, not a public IP