# Finding My Socket's Public IP Address?

Tags: python, networking

I'm trying to create the ability for a client to enter the IP address/port of a server and connect to it. In order to do this, I need the server's public IP address/port. Is there a good way to do this? What I've tried so far is...

```
ip_address = urllib.request.urlopen(<my web server>).read()
```

with the web server just containing the php script:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]?>
```

And just storing the port from the

```
s.bind(('', port))
```

Connecting to this ip address and port times out. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
OK so basically I'm trying to establish a connection over the internet, without knowing exactly what my router is going to be doing. I can use a webserver with any code if necessary, as I have access to permanent webspace. This is what I have right now.

Server:

```
import urllib.request
import threading
import socket

socket_list = []
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('', 0))

s.listen(10)


def listener(socket):
    while(1):
        data = socket.recv(1024)
        print (data)

def accepter():
    while(1):
        socket, addr = s.accept()
        socket_list.append(socket)
        threading.Thread(target = listener, args = (socket,)).start()

ip_address = (urllib.request.urlopen("<MY WEB SERVER HERE>").read()).decode('utf-8')
print (ip_address)
print (s.getsockname()[1])

threading.Thread(target = accepter, args = ()).start()
```

Client:

```
import socket

print ("Enter IP Address")
ip_address = input()
print ("Enter Port")
port = int(input())

s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2.connect((ip_address, port))s2.send("Connected!")
s2.close()
```

When I run the client I'm entering the IP address and port that are outputted by the server. Needless to say, this doesn't work.

Comment: So you need *your* public IP or some external server's?  Question is a little confusing as to which side of the pipe you're operating on.

Comment: I need my IP address.

Comment: I am indeed the server. I'm listening, but I don't know where--which is the problem.

Comment: post more code I'm getting confused.

Comment: related: [Finding a public facing IP address in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/166545/4279)

Comment: related but different sebastian. The main problem right now seems to be the port forwarding, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @SwiftCore: The port is static. Find out once how your network is configured.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was a good question you can do it like this if you didn't want to have your server set up like you have:

```
""" Easy IP Getter """
import json
import urllib2

info = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen("http://jsonip.com").read())
ip = info["ip"]
print ip
```

It depends on an outside service however which isn't the best, if they stop working you stop working.

Comment: I guess I should also say that I need the port number? Should I try and set up a connection through a webserver to determine the port? I have webspace I can use.