# Finding network (external) IP addresses using Python

Tags: python, ip, python-2.x

I want to know my internet provider (external) IP address (broadband or something else) with Python.

There are multiple machines are connected to that network. I tried in different way's but I got only the local and public IP my machine. How do I find my external IP address through Python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what ways have you tried?

Comment: i have tried this, `import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`.Now i am getting ip address that is assigned to my machine. Not network provider's ip address

Comment: @timgeb, if you see this link http://ipinfodb.com/ you can know what exactly i want.Here whole information is coming like, country, city, provider ip etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a public facing IP address in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166545/finding-a-public-facing-ip-address-in-python)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this script :

```
import urllib, json

data = json.loads(urllib.urlopen("http://ip.jsontest.com/").read())
print data["ip"]
```

Without json :

```
import urllib, re

data = re.search('"([0-9.]*)"', urllib.urlopen("http://ip.jsontest.com/").read()).group(1)
print data
```

---

Other way it was to parse ifconfig (= linux) or ipconfig (= windows) command but take care with translated Windows System
(ipconfig was translated).

Example of lib for linux :
[ifparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ifparser/).

Comment: Very elegant answer !

Answer (score 14):

Secure option (with `https` support)

```
from requests import get

get('https://ipapi.co/ip/').text
```

Complete [JSON response](https://ipapi.co/json/)

P.S. `requests` module is convenient for `https` support. You can try [httplib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146467/6250071) though.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use an external source you trust. Python2.x:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import json
url = 'http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php'
info = json.loads(urlopen(url).read())
print(info['ip'])
```

If you want more info, you can print more values from `info`.

Non-python oneliner:

```
wget -q -O- icanhazip.com
```

Comment: @Mulagala changed my answer to python2.7

Comment: How can i get the user's location to store last logged in place

Comment: `info` is a dictionary, it has no order. Each time you print it the order will be different.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you, My requirement is to find my users location to save last logged in place.Here code is executing on my server so i am getting my location , Now i need my client location those who are logging into my site, Please help me if you know .Thanks in advacne

Comment: I think you should maybe open a new question, it's hard to answer in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22157882/5687894

TL;DR:

```
import ipgetter
ip=ipgetter.myip()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simplest solution is

```
f = requests.request('GET', 'http://myip.dnsomatic.com')
ip = f.text
```

Thats all.

Comment: Do note that it does require the non-default additional [Python Requests module](http://www.python-requests.org).

Comment: Better and more elegant

Answer (score -1):

my website [http;//botliam.com/1.php](https://www.botliam.com/1.php) outputs your ip so you only need these 3 lines to get your ip.

```
import requests
page = requests.get('http://botliam.com/1.php')
ip = page.text
```

what its doing is:

- opens my webpage and calls it "page"
- sets "ip" to the contents of the "page"

if you want your own server to return your external ip instead of relying on my site the code for it is below:

```
<?php
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
echo "$ip";
?>
```